# Automount external hdd in fluxbox ubuntu -12.10 commandline install

Tags: 12.10, mount, automount, fluxbox

I did the following:

Install command line interface with ubuntu alternate install 12.10 in vmwareplayer5(9.2.2)
After the base system was installed: 
sudo apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade,
sudo apt-get install xinit xorg fluxbox build-essential lxterminal gksu leafpad pcmanfm mc chromium-browser, this works. I also installed vmwaretools.

The problem is that usb hdd or thumb drives won't mount unless I mount them through commandline. I'm new at building fluxbox so any help regarding automounting would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building from the Base system, it may be the case that the package needed for auto-mount have not been installed.

Try installing nautilus. (`sudo apt-get install nautilus`).

Since `nautilus` can mount your external drives, all packages required for mounting your external file-systems would have also been installed as dependencies.

Now, you can easily mount external drives by opening nautilus and selecting the relevant entry from the Left Pane.

Comment: @ Karthik: Thanks for reacting, instead of using nautilus I'm using  pcmanfm (lightweight filemanager) which also usually mounts anything as long as lxde or xfce are being used. The problem lies with fluxbox I think.