# Ubuntu System Messed Up!

Tags: unity, gnome, graphics, fluxbox

I decided to install fluxbox on my system recently, just to try it out, so I installed it and everything executed fine.  I logged into the fluxbox desktop and messed around with it for a while, then shut the computer down.  The next time I started up my laptop I booted into gnome fallback and all the graphics were messed up.  It was a black screen, with no borders, the only thing on the screen was my curser.  I tried all the normal approaches to graphics problems, resetting unity (I know gnome fallback doesn't use it but whatever), and removing and re-installing all the xorg drivers. The only thing that changed is when I login to any desktop (Gnome, Ubuntu, etc.) the screen shows some text that blinks once and disappears, then kicks me back to the login screen.  I have no idea what to do at this point, and I don't want to delete and re-install Ubuntu and lose all my data.  Please help!

Comment: For a detailed answer, you should give more details in your description.  For example, did you take all the defaults when installing?  Did you use a guide of which you could post a link to?  Did you modify anything while 'messing around,' or did you just use programs normally?  The output from commands may also help, such as: `lsb_release -a` or `sudo lshw`

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made my question very vague. I used sources such as this link: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-removeinstall-and-reconfigure-xorg-without-reinstalling-ubuntu.html  and also commands such as unity--reset.  I can only access the command line and guest mode to enter commands.  I didn't modify anything when I tried out Fluxbox, I just opened it and looked at the menus. I installed fluxbox, and didn't modify any of the settings.  I will try to get some command output now.

Comment: After inputing lsb_release it returned this output: "No LSB modules are available.".  When I entered the sudo lshw command the console returned a bunch of text that I can't scroll up to read. (I am using Ctrl + Alt + F4 to access the command line.)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I am not a Fluxbox guru.  If I were in your situation though, I would read these links and re-approach the issue: [Link 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fluxbox), [Link 2](http://www.fluxbox.org).

Link 1 gives the command to "Restart the Xsession":

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

But, logging out does the same (which you've tried).  If you can install the software, then you can also uninstall it, possibly like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove fluxbox

or
sudo apt-get purge fluxbox
```

"Ctrl-Alt-t" is another hotkey to get to the Terminal.  Good luck.

**EDIT** 
Try [installing Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/227026/192800):

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Comment: Same result, I don't think the errors are linked to Fluxbox, because I completely purged the files! Hmmmm... Any more ideas?

Comment: looking through [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/fluxbox) now

Comment: Is there any way I could re-install Ubuntu and still keep all my stuff in the /home folder?  I can't copy it over because I can't access the gui, except for through guest mode, which doesn't have any permissions.  The installer doesn't recognize that I have a previous installation, so I can't go that route.

Comment: Nautilus is already installed.

Comment: Absolutely, try: `gksudo nautilus` for a GUI with permissions.  A USB flash drive would be ideal for saving your /home directory.

Comment: In the guest user?  Because I can't open anything but guest and the command line from the login screen that has no gui at all.